# Какие метрики лучше всего использовать в задаче бинарной классификации

Tags: машинное-обучение

Допустим, в задаче бинарной классификации, доля одного класса составляет 95% выборки. Какие метрики лучше всего использовать для этой модели?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно в случае такого дисбаланса классов при бинарной классификации используют метрику [ROC AUC](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html), хотя и она тоже имеет границы применимости и при ещё более сильном имбалансе (например 100:1) её тоже нужно использовать с осторожностью.

Почему собственно используют `ROC AUC` вместо, например, `Accuracy`. Для `Accuracy` не важно, какой класс правильно предсказан, главное, чтобы было побольше верных предсказаний в принципе. Получается, если при дисбалансе классов 95% на 5% просто предсказать всем сэмплам значение того класса, которого больше, то `Accuracy` будет `0.95` (по шкале от `0` до `1`) при том, что мы не определили правильно ни одного сэмпла того класса, которого у нас мало. Это как-то нехорошо. А вот `ROC AUC` при выставлении всем сэмплам одного и того же класса (любого из двух) даст метрику `0.5` (по шкале от `0` до `1`), что гораздо более информативно. `ROC AUC` заставляет нас правильно предсказывать не просто какой-то процент сэмплов от их общего кол-ва, а какой-то процент сэмплов от того класса, к которому они принадлежат на самом деле.

Comment: А можете пояснить, пожалуйста, почему?

Comment: @LightM Немного пояснил

Answer (score 0):

При разбалансированных данных первое, что приходит на ум это:

- ROC AUC, как уже написал в своем ответе уважаемый CrazyElf
- [F1 Score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-score) ([f1_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html) из sklearn).

Во многих статьях утверждают, что при сильной разбалансировке лучше все-таки использовать `F1 Score` в качестве метрики.

PS [очень хороший и подробный ответ на данный вопрос в англоязычной версии SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52892413/5741205)